# Class will compile for Tests/Console but not in Asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, compiler-construction

I have a simple interface:

```
public interface IVisitorsLogController  
{
    List<VisitorsLog> GetVisitorsLog();
    int GetUniqueSubscribersCount();
    int GetVisitorsCount();
    string GetVisitorsSummary();
}
```

the class VisitorsLogController implements this interface.

From a console application or a TestFixture - no problem - the console/test fixture compile perfectly.

However, from an Asp.Net web site (not application) in the same solution with this code in the code behind

```
private IVisitorsLogController ctl;

protected int GetUniqueMembersCount()
{
    ctl = new VisitorsLogController();
    return ctl.GetUniqueSubscribersCount();        
}
```

the compiler throws this exception:

> Error 1   'WebSiteBusinessRules.Interfaces.IVisitorsLogController'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'GetUniqueSubscribersCount' and no
>   extension method
>   'GetUniqueSubscribersCount' accepting
>   a first argument of type
>   'WebSiteBusinessRules.Interfaces.IVisitorsLogController'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

yet for this code in the same file:

```
  protected static int GetVisitorsCount()
{
    return VisitorsLogController.Instance.GetVisitorsCount(DateTime.Today);
}
```

the compiler compiles these lines without complaining. In fact if I add anything new to the Interface the compiler now complains when trying to compile the asp.net page.

It can't be a missing using directive or assembly reference otherwise both methods would fail.

This is driving me nuts!

Any thoughts please?

Thanks,

Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem the other important bit of code would be VisitorsLogController, wouldn't it? It looks like VisitorsLogController is implementing a *different* IVistorsLogController interface.

Right clicking and GoTo Definition should clear things up, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest, can you compile the following line:

```
ctl = VisitorsLogController.Instance;
```

? I'm just wondering if somehow you've got two interfaces named the same thing.

What does Intellisense prompt you with when you type `ctl.` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>?

Comment: John - yes that compiles fine. However as soon as I put in ctl.GetUniqueMembersCount() the compilation fails.
Typing ctl.and Ctl+Space shows me GetUniqueMembersCount in the list. (I couldn't upload my screenshot).

Comment: So if you accept Intellisense's own suggestion, it fails to build? Yikes. I suggest restarting Visual Studio and doing as clean a build as you can. It sounds like something's out of whack.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking the namespaces on each of the files involved and make sure that you don't have a conflict or a namespace that you are not expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The solution contains the web site and three class projects (Data Layer, Service Layer and Core Services). They are added as references to the web site as Projects. 
I had compiled the solution at one point for Release - published the site, and then changed the config to Debug.

Evidently what had happened was that the Release dll's in the /bin file of the website were not being overwritten by the new Debug dll's. I manually deleted all the files in the /bin directory, and lo and behold - everything compiled perfectly.

So Mark and John - you were both spot on - I effectively did have two interfaces named the same thing.

Thanks very much for your help - if you hadn't given me these pointers I would never have finally worked it out.